# Accessing Java API in JAR file using Ionic 4

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on mobile app (Android) using Ionic 4. I was given a JAR file that supposedly contains the API that sends out some commands via tablet's USB port. The API in the JAR file is written in Java and Ionic project is in Angular, I have no idea how to call the Java API in typescript environment.

Is that even possible? Is that how the ionic native camera, barcode scanner libraries are developed?

Answer (score 0):

To access Android Java native APIs, we need to create a Cordova plugin. You need to write the code in Java for the core logic and Javascript for the API that can be called by Ionic Native(refer below).

Here are some useful links to get started:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html

When writing the Java code for Cordova plugin, you can import the packages from another JAR file and uses the library to achieve what you want to achieve.

After that, we need to create a new Ionic Native interface, a TypeScript wrapper, to enabled communication from Ionic App to Cordova plugin. Here's the guide:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure How you want. But One thing i am doing is below :
-> Under src, create configuration ts file where you can declare base url and other paths. Then, create service file under app. You can call your url from your api, import config file inside service.ts file. You can code retrieve/ create / delete /update within service file. Then, you can call service file from ionic pages.ts.